# Display value of a global variable in a message

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am having what I believe to be a syntax issue in Common Lisp. I have a global variable, `*LOC*`, I can set its initial value and change it. My issue isn't with the variable, it works fine, it is when I try to display a message with its value.

For example, When i use an if statement and say something like:

```
(if ( UPSTAIRSP *LOC*)

           (progn (princ "I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE *LOC*"))
           (progn (princ "I AM DOWNSTAIRS IN THE *LOC*"))
)
```

I will get:

`I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE *LOC*`

I'm pretty sure it is because my variable is in the quotations, but I don't know how else to express it.

Comment: Common Lisp does not do string interpolation by default. It's possible to write string interpolation libraries, then use those.

Answer (score 9):

First, you don't need to use `progn` if you only have a single expression in one of the `IF` branches.
Now, as you said, variables are not interpolated in strings.
For actual string interpolation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102882/124319), but I think you should first try to learn  a little more about the basics.

You could print things like so:

```
(if (upstairsp *LOC*)
  (progn 
    (princ "I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE ")
    (princ *LOC*))
  (progn 
    (princ "I AM DOWNSTAIRS IN THE ")
    (princ *LOC*)))
```

Generally, when you spot [`IF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm) with [`PROGN`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm), chances are that you need [`COND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm). Here this is not necessary because you print `*LOC*` in both branches and you can factor that outside of the conditional.

```
(progn
  (if (upstairsp *LOC*)
    (princ "I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE ")
    (princ "I AM DOWNSTAIRS IN THE "))
  (princ *LOC*))
```

But you should probably use [`FORMAT`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) instead.
For example:

```
(if (upstairsp *LOC*)
  (format t "I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE ~A" *LOC*)
  (format t "I AM DOWNSTAIRS IN THE ~A" *LOC*))
```

In fact, `FORMAT` supports conditional directives.
Below, the return value of `(upstairsp *LOC*)`, a boolean, is used in the `~:[...~;...~]` directive to select which text to print:

```
(format t 
        "I AM ~:[DOWNSTAIRS~;UPSTAIRS~] IN THE ~A"
        (upstairsp *LOC*)
        *LOC*)
```

Have a look at [A Few Format Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) (Practical Common Lisp, Seibel) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

In Common Lisp you can compose string and values either for printing or for other purposes with the [`format` operator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm#format):

```
(if (upstairsp *LOC*)
    (format t "I AM UPSTAIRS IN THE ~a" *LOC*)
    (format t "I AM DOWNSTAIRS IN THE ~a" *LOC*"))
```

The first parameter of format is a stream (or `T` for the standard output), to print the message on that stream, or `NIL` to produce a formatted string. You can find all the details in tha [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm).